# Regular expression to find files that begin with, contain or end with series of chars

Tags: regex

Firstly, the answer must be using REGEX, do not suggest string manipulation using .NET or Java etc...

I need to find if a full file name, excluding path, contains a series of chars.

I am able to search the file name but can't get past the directories and subdirectories.

So ie:

A pattern of he.+.txt would match c:\temp\help.txt but also matches c:\hemp\felp.txt, I am trying to avoid the later.

I am able extract to file name from the directory by using expression [^\]+$ but not familiar enough with regex to accomplish what I want with a single expression. I began looking into grouping too.

Comment: You are going to need to provide some more examples, as your opening explanation ("*including path*") completely contradicts your later anti-example ("*I am trying to avoid the later.*").

Comment: A regexp expression that would match only the file name portion of a full file path. So an expression like he.+\.txt would match 1 & 2 but I want to avoid having 2 included.

1.c:\temp\help.txt
2.c:\hemp\felp.txt

Comment: Do you understand how "*I need to find if a full file name, including path begins with, contains or ends with a series of chars.*" could be confusing?

Comment: Yes, I can see how it can be confusing. Not always easy to describe exactly what is needed on the first attempt. I'll be happy to clarify it further, if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already had the building blocks all lined up:

```
\bhe[^\\]*\.txt$
```

would only match `c:\temp\help.txt` and not `c:\hemp\felp.txt` or `c:\temp\shelp.txt`.

**Explanation:**

```
\b      # Start of alphanumeric word
he      # Match "he"
[^\\]*  # Match any number of characters except backslashes
\.txt   # Match ".txt"
$       # Make sure we're at the end of the string
```

If you want to make sure that the match starts after a `\` character (or possibly the start of the string if there is no path before the filename), you can use a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) if your regex engine supports them:

```
(?<=^|\\)he[^\\]*\.txt$
```

`(?<=^|\\)` means "Assert that the current position is at the start of the string (`^`) or right after a backslash.

Comment: How do I restrict matches to filenames that only begin with "he", with your solution filenames with c:\temp\shelp.txt would also match.

Comment: @domenicr - One way is `(?:^|(?<=\\))he[^\\]*\.txt$`

Comment: Never mind \b does the trick at the beginning of the pattern like
\bhe[^\\\]*\.txt$

Comment: Just so you know `\bhe[^\\]*\.txt$` \b in this case matches all punctuation, extended ascii, all control codes and whitespace .. essentially %65 of x0-xFF. Primarily of concern it matches the dash `-`